# How to restrict output in shell script of a command executing in loop

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, ubuntu-16.04

I'm having a shell script as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


#Packages list

declare -a packages=( git build_essential node )
declare -a packages_status

# installing=`apt-get install -y `
installing="echo "

for i in "${packages[@]}"
do
    packages_status[$i]=$(dpkg-query -W -f='${status}' $i | grep "install ok installed")
    # echo ${packages_status[$i]}
done
```

The line of code

```
packages_status[$i]=$(dpkg-query -W -f='${status}' $i | grep "install ok installed")
```

produces the following output

> dpkg-query: no packages found matching build_essential
>
> dpkg-query: no packages found matching node

I want that LOC to execute without producing any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dpkg-query` command ouputs errors to stderr, not stdout.
So, you should link the two channels before piping to grep:

```
packages_status[$i]=$(dpkg-query -W -f='${status}' $i 2>&1 | grep "install ok installed")
```

This way the script will only print lines "install ok installed" for installed packages.

Answer (score 1):

In order not to see error output, you can redirect that output (stream number 2) to the `NULL` device:

```
Do_Whatever 2>/dev/null
```

In order not to see any output, you can redirect normal output (stream number 1) to the `NULL` device and redirect error output there too:

```
Do_Whatever >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks Dominique for the repy. Actually I was making a custom script to set up a complete dev environment in Vagrant. So I cannot redirect the entire output of the script to NULL